# Same class is in multiple jar

Tags: java, jar

I have several jars containing the exact same class.

Lets say for example, A.jar and B.jar have the same class Hello.class. What will happen if I run the following:

java -classpath A.jar;B.jar com.testing.testcode

My question is whether it will run or not? As from my understanding class loader will scan the classpath and it will return whatever Hello.class it finds first.

I know I can avoid this problem if I use OSGi for loading a particular class.

But what my question is – whether this will run or not? Or the java -classpath A.jar;B.jar com.testing.testcode will break down for having two version of the same class.

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Was the result confusing?

Comment: Compiler will be silent as long as you don't use the conflicting class, as soon as you use, you need to use with package.classname format. Else code won't compile.

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Note that it is best to avoid ambiguous situations like these :).

Comment: @PradeepSimha I think Baishakh means that there are two classes with the same fully qualified name (i.e. `Hello` is in the default package, assuming these names are accurate).  So it's not about prepending packages to disambiguate, it's about what happens with a "full" name clash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work and the first Hello class in the classpath will be used, so in this case, the one from the A.jar

Comment: *Usually* it will work, and the first version of the class in the classpath will be the one used.  However, there are situations where a class referencing the problem class may "express a preference" for the version in the referencing class's jar.  This can result the "same" class being loaded twice, which is not always a problem but can be.

Comment: How a situation can arise i.e. how it will express a preference" for the version in the referencing class's jar?

Comment: @Baishakh - It has to do with custom class loaders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The class path is a "path". The first match is taken.

There is a boot class path which is examined first and this included the JARs in the JRE.  BTW You can prepend these and override system classes but you are not supposed to and it might not be allowed in your license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you include the jar in your classpath, on startup/ on application class gets loaded into the container.

Now whether your code will work or not will depend on which jar gets loaded first in your container and accordingly if you are lucky then in your current setup it will work else you **might** get some error saying that `method1 doesn't accept Type1 it should accept Type2`.

Comment: Or you may get a class cast exception casting TheClass to TheClass, if TheClass gets loaded twice.